# I want to grab the Values in a nested dictionary and make it as a fresh dictionary and Later I want to convert it into a df. How Can I do that?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

##### Current data

```py
Some_dict = {0: {},
             1: {'A': ['apple']},
             2: {},
             3: {'B': ['orange', 'papaya']},
             4: {'C': ['mango', 'berries', 'grape']}}
```

##### I want

```
my_dict =   { {},
            {'A': ['apple']}, 
            {{},
            {'B': ['orange','papaya']},
            {'C': ['mango', 'berries', 'grape']}}
```

Then I want to make `my_dict` as a `dataframe`:

| name | fruits |
| --- | --- |
| {} |  |
| A | apple |
| {} |  |
| B | orange |
| B | papaya |
| C | mango |
| C | berries |
| C | grape |

How can I do that in pandas and in python?

Thanks

Comment: So you want a list of dictionaries?

Comment: What you want is a set, not a dictionary - this can be implemented relatively the same way as whitespaces suggestion.

Comment: @all, I just want the Values from Some_dict which is my desired dictionary and make it into a data frame as I  have shown in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
 my_fruit_list = []
    for v in d.values():
        if not v:
            my_fruit_list.append([{}, ""])
        else:
            key = list(v.keys())[0]
            my_fruit_list.append([key, v[key]])
    print(my_fruit_list)
```

Comment: Yea pretty much it but when I convert it into dataframe. The fruits come in as a list.
Like this:

B [orange, papaya]

But I wanted

|name|  fruits|

|B |    orange|
|B |    papaya|


In this format.

Comment: @oazedlium I am not familiar with Pandas sorry about that, but I think the key is to iterate through the keys of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

you need the list of values

```
new_dictionary_list = [x for x in some_dict.values()]
```

now,

you can make a data frame using

```
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'name':[list(x.items())[0][0] for x in new_dictionary_list], 'fruits':[list(x.items())[0][1] for x in new_dictionary_list]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got an answer on how to get to `my_dict`, for creating a DataFrame of your original data you could do the following to create a pair of data for each row:

```py
tmp = []
for key,value in some_dict.items():
    if value:
        tmp.extend([(k,v) for k, vals in value.items() for v in vals])
    else:
        tmp.append(('',''))
print(tmp)

out = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['name', 'fruits'])
print(out)
```

Output:

```
# tmp 

[('', ''), ('A', 'apple'), ('', ''), ('B', 'orange'), ('B', 'papaya'), ('C', 'mango'), ('C', 'berries'), ('C', 'grape')]

# out

  name   fruits
0              
1    A    apple
2              
3    B   orange
4    B   papaya
5    C    mango
6    C  berries
7    C    grape
```